# SuluArticleBundle installed, but Articles option not available in Admin menu

Tags: symfony, content-management-system, php-7, elasticsearch-5, sulu

I started working with Sulu, and tried to implement the optional ArticleBundle. I used [this documentation](https://github.com/sulu/SuluArticleBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md) and composer installed `elasticsearch 5.0.6` along with the bundle. All configuration files have been configured like the documentation, and while the server is starting, there is still no "Article" options like [in the Sulu demo](https://sulu.rocks) (you can log in with admin / admin and check it out).
I also encountered the error `No alive nodes in your cluster` while performing the last commands that are related to ElasticSearch. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen that the SuluArticleBundle has a dependency to elasticsearch (which is a third party application). This has to be started before running sulu with the article-bundle. Additionally you have to add the security-context to the user-role. Open the User Role of your user and simply add it.